# Postgresql Boolean field doesnt accept 0 or 1 as valid entry

Tags: sql, postgresql, flask, boolean, flask-sqlalchemy

I have set up a postgresql database for a flask project. Ihave a column `ticked` of boolean type in my project. When I try to write into the db. Here's the error I get :
`column "ticked" is of type boolean but expression is of type integer`
It is true that I am trying to create my record with an integer value : `1`.
However this works perfectly fine on my coworkers environment. I first thought that it was because I was not running on psql last version but I updated psql to version 10.1 and I still have this issue.

We use sqlalchemy to generate the tables. Here's the model related to the problematic columns:

```
class Email(db.Model):

__tablename__ = "emails"

email = db.Column(db.String(254), primary_key=True)
ticked = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False)
primary = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False)
```

Do you know why psql is not accepting 0 or 1 values for boolean field ?

Comment: Please could you [edit] the question to include the *exact* SQL you're running. Is your colleague running exactly the same SQL? If not, post what they're running here, too, so we can help you understand the difference.

Comment: We are creating the tables using flask module`SqlAlchemy`, ill post the code related to the problematic columns

Answer (score 4):

you need to properly cast them:

```
t=# select 1::boolean, 0::boolean;
 bool | bool
------+------
 t    | f
(1 row)
```

or SQL compatible:

```
t=# select cast (1 as boolean), cast (0 as boolean);
 bool | bool
------+------
 t    | f
(1 row)
```

or another postgres specific:

```
t=# select boolean '1', boolean '0';
 bool | bool
------+------
 t    | f
(1 row)
```

also there's implicit cast of text to boolean:

```
t=# create table b(v boolean);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into b values ('0');
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from b;
 v
---
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: I went in my db `psql users` and typed `select 1::boolean, 0::boolean;` and got same output as you. However im still getting the error I mentioned in my question...

Comment: As I understand it, the `boolean '0'` isn't strictly speaking a cast - it's a syntax for writing a boolean literal. Similarly, the last example probably never sees the input as a `text` value, only as an "unknown literal", which it detects the type for. It's a subtle distinction, but occasionally there are situations where it matters, and you get error messages about "unknown type".

Comment: @DavidGeismar that's odd - I have only `not implicit` cast of integer to boolean..

Answer (score 0):

Actually It was not the version of psql that was the problem, but my version of sqlAlchemy. I was 1.1.13 and now that I have upgraded to 1.2.1 I dont have the error anymore